# Convert AC to DC using Phase Shift Oscillator

Tags: analog, oscillator, simulation, multisim, phase-shift

from what I know, we can convert DC to AC by using Phase Shift Oscillators. I'm able to pull off the manual calculations, but as for simulation on Multisim 14.2, I didn't get the desired graph(phase shifted). Maybe my understanding is wrong, so please let me know how can I make the following circuit to oscillate.[image]

Comment: Why R3 and R4?  They are in parallel.  A single resistor could be used instead of two.

Comment: This oscillator needs an inverting gain factor of (slightly above) 29.

Comment: What are you trying to graph?  If you're doing a simulation, you need to kick-start the oscillation.

Comment: That circuit won’t oscillate. Go google an opamp phase shift oscillator and try that. Try and pick a google source that appears reputable in engineering. You could take punt at connecting  R4 to the opamp output instead of where it connects to R3. That would look more reasonable. Also use a faster opamp. 741s are basically poor at oscillators in the mid kHz range. In fact they are poor at everything.